# How to search tweets in Twitter API from data endpoint in dev environment using cURL?

Tags: curl, twitter, cmd, get

I want to search some tweets and **GET** some data from twitter API using `dev` environment and `data` endpoint. I produced `consumer_key`, `consumer_secret`, `access_token`, and `access_token_secret`. Now, I want to know How can I send a request to twitter API using `cURL` in **cmd**. When I try the following *query*, I get an *error{bad Authentication}*. Please help me if you know how to write correct `cURL` request for accessing twitter `dev` and searching tweets in **cmd**. Thanks for all answers.
here is my `cURL` request:

```
curl --trace outputFile.txt "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/tweets/search/30day/my_dev_env_label.json?query=TwitterDev%20%5C%22search%20api%5C%22&maxResults=100" {"Authorization":"OAuth","consumer_key":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","consumer_secret":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","access_token":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","access_token_secret":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}
```

I have tried to write it like some existing examples here:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/premium-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. I decided to publish my answer because I think it might be helpful for some one in the future!
For sending a request to twitter API using **cURL**, the first step is generating `Bearer token` by having `API(consumer) key` and `API secret key` like the following:

```
curl -u "REPLACE_YOUR_API_KEY:REPLACE_YOUR_API_SECRET_KEY" --data "grant_type=client_credentials" "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token"
```

Then you'll receive a bearer token. by using this, replace your own parameters with capital words in the following request:

```
curl "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/tweets/search/PRODUCT/LABEL.json?query=QUERY_URL&maxResults=100&fromDate=YYYYMMDDHHMM&toDate=YYYYMMDDHHMM" -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_BEARER_TOKEN"
```

In the above request, YYYYMMDDHHMM is a date format like: 201907291530
So, It finished successfully!